# How do you get the tracks of the Home Videos window in iTunes 11 with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

Not sure if I'm missing something, but my old go to in AppleScript for getting a selection of tracks seems to specifically NOT work on the new Movies > Home Videos view in iTunes 11.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get selection from browser window 1
end tell
```

Also tried below as implied here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4576448?start=0&tstart=0

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get selection
end tell
```

If I'm viewing the Home Videos collection, this returns {} regardless of what I have selected. If I switch to Movies > Movies and select some entries, this works as expected. Same if I'm viewing a playlist under Music.

Comment: Does it help if you use "front window" or "front playlist window" instead of "browser window 1"?